# Site loading speed is very slow

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization, pagespeed

My client's Magento site page load speed is very slow. What can I do to decrease page load time?

The site url is desibazaar.pk.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First determine if it's front end rendering or the actual script execution that is slow. Check with the developer console in your browser for the *Time To First Byte*. This is how long the script take to process on the server

[image]

In the screenshot you can see it's quite low (200ms) so in this case the problem wouldn't be on the server but on front end. Now if it's over, let's say, a second you might want to optimize.

Before you slap on some boosters and extra caching which isn't a fix just a patch or band aid to hide the real issue try to figure out what exactly is slow. You can use several tools also for that.

**Slow queries**

Magento can be quite heavy on the database so turning on the Slow Query Log might be a good place to start. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608232/387136) on how to turn it on. The log will show you any query that takes longer than X seconds.

**Profilers**

Profilers help you gain insight into whats going on in your code. For Magento I would recommend starting with [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler). Just install it and turn it on. On the front end it'll give you an output like this:

[image]

Expand the results and check for large red blocks. Those are the actual times it took a certain part of the code to process. Look out for any 3rd party modules that are taking up a lot of time or memory.

Another great tool is **[Black fire](https://blackfire.io/)**. Since Aoe_Profiler is a module in Magento it doesn't show the underlying php processes and can crash on large installations with a lot of modules. Black fire runs on the server.
With a hackathon we set up a [Vagrant box with black fire](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/BlackfireMagentoVagrant) you can use. Just put your project on there and fire it up. Check the Black fire site for more info how to use it.

Last one is probably my favorite: **[New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)**.

Unfortunately it's a paid service although they provide a free trial for pro accounts. After installing it on your server and connecting the profile wait a couple of hours for data to come in. Make sure there is some traffic on the shop tho.

[image]

New Relic also has [a blog post on how to debug Magento](https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/08/25/magento-strategery-debugging/) which I can recommend. Also check out the [ProxiBlue New Relic](https://github.com/ProxiBlue/NewRelic) module for extra Magento data in New Relic.

Basically this will show you all of the above described features like slow queries, the processes in PHP etc and display it in easy graphs and tables. This should give you great insight in what is the issue in your installation.

**And from here**
Now that you know what is causing the low performance you can move on to solving it. Check forums like this one or Google for the part or module of Magento that is slow. A lot of issues are well known and others have solved it before. Or, if you can't find a solution post your question here and include your findings in the question

Comment: Excellent.. Thanks for the insight about "BlackFire"

Answer (score 12):

Site speed optimization in Magento is very vast topic.
This is one link which can help you,

http://www.gxjansen.com/blog/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Taking a gist of it,

You need to concentrate on two aspects,
1. Frontend optimization
2. Backend optimization

**Frontend optimization**

1. You can install Fooman Speedster - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/speedster-by-fooman.html and enable css , js merge
2. Enable Magento block caching in admin.
3. Enable Gzip compression

**Backend Optimization**

1. You can configure Varnish for full page caching
2. Enable complication in backend.
3. Enable flat structure for catalog (category and products)

Answer (score 2):

Magento is a great e-commerce framework. It has tons of features and you can really build a scalable e-commerce platform. I used Magento in my latest project and faced this speed issue. After doing some research and modification I really sped up my website.

**Server Optimization**

- Use Nginx as web server
- Move MySQL to different server with master-slave replica. If you are on AWS use RDS for MySQL.
- Optimize Nginx & Php-fpm
- enable gzip compression
- Enable Browser cache

**Magento Settings**

- Disable all unnecessary extensions
- Merge CSS and JavaScript files
- Disable Log
- Clean up Magento log tables
- Enable External full page cache

**Install Redis Cache, APC  Opcode & Full Page Cache extension**
 - Install PHP Accelerators
 - Install Redis cache for backend & session caching
 - Install Lesti FPC

**Image Optimization & YSlow**
 - on an average 56 percent of a website’s page weight is made up of images. Optimizing your product images can dramatically increase the speed of your pages as this decreases their download times. 
 - Scan your website through gtmetrix or Pingdom and follow their optimization suggestions.

**Use CDN**

You can read details about this on my website: http://www.ranjeetvimal.com/tips-to-speed-up-magento-1-9-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple little tricks I found to help speed up your site you might want to try:

Defer Image loading by adding this to the `/template/page/html/head.phtml`

```
<script>
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Then in `/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` change your image links like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4AQQATUqB0EhKgAAAAxJREFUCNdj+P//PwAF/gL+3MxZ5wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Another one is to "Pre Gzip" all your javascripts and CSS files then add this to your `.htaccess`.

```
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    ##### serve pre gziped files #####
    # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
    # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [L,QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [L,QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a shared hosting environment it is very difficult to achieve good speed as one do not have full control over server and the resource is used by several other websites, but if you are on dedicated server and have full admin access try varnish cache.

other things you can do -

1.Combine JS and CSS files

```
Magento admin -> System Configuration -> Developer -> Under “Javascript Settings”, change “Merge Javascript Files” to YES.
Magento admin -> System Configuration -> Developer -> Under “CSS Settings”, change “Merge CSS Files” to YES
```

2.Enable Output Compression, Expires Headers and Disable ETags in .htaccess file 
see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745165/3114253

3. Use CDN if Possible
4. Use Magento’s Compilation feature. It’s reported to give you a 25%-50% performance boost: System > Config. > Tools > Compilation.
5. Show lesser no. of Product in Product listing Page.
6. Enable flat catalog.

From the Magento administrator interface, go to System > Configuration > Catalog.
Under Frontend, change Use Flat Catalog Category to YES.
If desired, under Frontend, change Use Flat Catalog Product to YES.
Clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to speed up your frontend:

- use a CDN for images (!) and reduce the image size
- concatenate CSS and JS
- load JS before the closing body tag
- use asynchronous js loading whenever possible
- use image sprites or an icon-font instead of thousands of png files
- reduce unused CSS
- generate a [critical path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/?hl=en) for your css

Backend:

- use an additional cache like varnish (TTFB < 15ms) or [LestiFpc](https://gordonlesti.com/how-does-lesti-fpc-work/)
- profile your page-loading and complex MySQL Queries and fix them
- activate gzip, etags, browser-cache etc. via .htaccess
- use MySQL on a single Server

Comment: Please do not link to paid services with your invitation URL for your own personal gain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, it doesn't matter you run Magento 1 or Magento 2:

- **Optimize time to first byte** (TTFB): you could use an online profiler for this (tideways, new relic or similar, just google for it, they are all good). Magento comes with a built-in profiler, but its functionality is limited and sometimes hard to interpret.

Profiler can show you what code takes most time to be executed:

[image]

In the example above `array_flip` is executed too many times and it takes too long, maybe there is an opportunity to optimize here.

- Do a **3rd-party extension audit**. From my experiencing [speeding up](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento)  Magento sites, most slow sites are slow because of a poorly coded custom plugin they installed.

Turn all custom modules off and see if it makes any difference. If it does - turn them on one by one and see which one breaks performance.

- Switch to the default **Luma theme**. It could be that your theme files have loops and other unoptimized structures. Switch back to the Luma theme and see if it makes the site faster. If it does - your custom theme is the problem and you need to investigate it further.
- Make sure your server has **Gzip** compression enabled.
- Convert all images to **WebP or AVIF** to cut on page weight. Use picture HTML tag to fall back to PNGs or JPEGs for those browsers that don't support WebPs and AVIFs.
- Enable **CSS/JS minification** and compression in Magento backend. With the latest Magento 2, you can turn HTML minification on as well.

Good luck!