# wait time of 14.83s of my website in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

The wait time of my magento website is 14.83s which is very high . How do i reduce it. I would require a solution as it is slowing down my website

Comment: Hi, Welcome to magento.stackexchange.com. Your question is too broad to expect a good answer here. You need to investigate on different parts of your shop setup.

Comment: could you give explain on what i need to investigate on my shop setup

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/82984/243

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is **quite broad**, I try to give an overview answer here which might help you getting further.

Things that affect your shop performace are:

- Server setup
- Number and quality of extensions you use
- Magento coding performance issues (see this [guide](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf) here)
- Apache/Nginx/MySQL configuration and optimization
- Frontend-issues like heaving loading of CSS & JavaScript, caching static files, etc.

So it's quite hard to tell from your question where to start.

If you want to investigate further, you can try the following things:

- Check your shop with the developer toolbar, check header fields, check times loading for various resources, maybe theres something in particular that takes a lot of time.
- Enable the profiler (either the Standard Magento profiler) or [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler). The profiler can help you identify parts of code which are used in the loading a slow page, and how long it takes to complete these parts.
- Check your configuration files (php.ini/.htaccess/mysql config) and optimize if for Magento