# How to speed up magento site?

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

My site is www.suresafety.com which is in Magento 1.9.2.0. It was working fine for the last 1.5 years, but from the last 2 months, it is too much slow. There are 1400 products in it.

Its speed in Speed Insight was 83 before 1 year. Now it is 39 which is not good for our e-commerce.

I have done all this on steps:

1. Combine CSS and JS Files

   - In the Magento Admin, go to System > Configuration > Developer.
   - Under “Javascript Settings”, change “Merge Javascript Files” to YES.
   - Under “CSS Settings”, change “Merge CSS Files” to YES.
   - Clear the cache.
2. Enable Flat Catalog

   - In the Magento Admin, go to System > Configuration > Catalog.
   - Under “Frontend”, change “Use Flat Catalog Category” to YES.
   - Under “Frontend”, change “Use Flat Catalog Product” to YES. (optional)
   - Clear the cache.
3. Make sure the section with the deflate compression rules is not commented to enable the default compression rules.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>

       ## enable apache served files compression
       ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

       # Insert filter on all content
       ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
       # Insert filter on selected content types only
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

       # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
       BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

       # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
       BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

       # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
       BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

       # Don't compress images
       SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

       # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
       #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Add expiration time for images, JS, CSS (`.htcaccess`)

   ```
   ##for image test
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>

       ExpiresActive On<br/>
       ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"<br/>
       ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"<br/>
       ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"<br/>
       ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"<br/>
       ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"<br/>
       ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"<br/>
       ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"<br/>
       ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"<br/>
       ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"<br/>
       ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"<br/>
       ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"<br/>

   </IfModule><br/>
   ```
5. Cpanel -> Optimize Website -> tic on 2nd option(Compress all content)
6. Download optimized images, CSS, JS from Page Insights (bottom)
7. Replace with the old one.

Answer (score 1):

This as a duplicate question of:
[Site loading speed is very slow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82984/site-loading-speed-is-very-slow).

For the Magento htaccess, you can use our htaccess based on html5boilerplate htaccess. see below:
https://gist.github.com/reillo/9030038e854ffa49d83e423415c7acf4

Magento requires server resources and if you think you have enough server resources, you can check your Magento Application performance using a profiler. You can use the profiler from [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler).