# Magento 1.9.2.4 very slow loading speed after new theme installed

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, pagespeed

I've installed a new theme, Porto, on my magento store and now my website is loading slower than a snail moves :(

I've done all the steps just as the documentation is saying and now... :(

I've tried to flush the cache but it didn't help.

They ask for the compiler to be disabled so i disabled it

Here is the full theme documentation:

http://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/documentation/

Can anybody please help me? X_X thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

hey for checking why your site is running very slow you need to follow few points which are:

1. Disable all unnecessary extensions
2. Merge your css and js it can be done from admin side.
3. Clean magento logs table.
4. Enable full page cache.

you can also refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82984/site-loading-speed-is-very-slow) hope this help.